# Summing up two matrices of distances among centroids

Tags: r, matrix, distance

I am ecologist, using mainly the 'vegan' R package. I want to combine ('cbind') 2 matrices (sample x species) but samples (row) are different.
I sampled within 24 sites, by using 2 distinct methods, fish assemblages (6 replicates) and macro-invertebrates assemblages (3 replicates). (See data below)
I want to compute the pairwise distances among sites considering both assemblages(using braycurtis dissimilarity), let's say I want to get the overall distances among sites.
I see 2 options:

option 1, averaging at the site scale fishes and macro-invertebrates abundances , 'cbind' the two mean abundances matrix and calculating bray-curtis

option 2, for each assemblage, computing bray-curtis and distances among sites centroids, and then summing up the 2 distance matrix.

Please, could you tell me if the option 2 is correct and more appropriate than option 1.

thank you in advance.

Pierre

```
 library(plyr)
 library(vegan)

#assemblage 1: 15 fish species, 6 replicates per site        
a1.env=data.frame(Habitat=paste("H",gl(2,12*6),sep=""),Site=paste("S",gl(24,6),sep=""),Replicate=rep(paste("R",1:6,sep=""),24))
summary(a1.env)

a1.bio=as.data.frame(replicate(15,rpois(144,sample(1:10,1))))
names(a1.bio)=paste("F",1:15,sep="")
a1.bio[1:72,]=2*a1.bio[1:72,]

#assemblage 2: 10 taxa of macro-invertebrates, 3 replicates per site
a2.env=a1.env[a1.env$Replicate%in%c("R1","R2","R3"),]
summary(a2.env)

a2.bio=as.data.frame(replicate(10,rpois(72,sample(10:100,1))))
names(a2.bio)=paste("I",1:10,sep="")
a2.bio[1:36,]=0.5*a2.bio[1:36,]


# "environmental" data at the sit scale
env=unique(a1.env[,c("Habitat","Site")])
env=env[order(env$Site),]

######## OPTION 1, averaging abundances and cbind

a1.bio.mean=ddply(cbind(a1.bio,a1.env),.(Habitat,Site),numcolwise(mean))
a1.bio.mean=a1.bio.mean[order(a1.bio.mean$Site),]

a2.bio.mean=ddply(cbind(a2.bio,a2.env),.(Habitat,Site),numcolwise(mean))
a2.bio.mean=a2.bio.mean[order(a2.bio.mean$Site),]

bio.mean=cbind(a1.bio.mean[,-c(1:2)],a2.bio.mean[,-c(1:2)])

dist.mean=vegdist(sqrt(bio.mean),"bray")


#######OPTION 2, computing for each assemblage distance among centroids and summing the 2 distances matrix
a1.dist=vegdist(sqrt(a1.bio),"bray")
a1.coord.centroid=betadisper(a1.dist,a1.env$Site)$centroids
a1.dist.centroid=vegdist(a1.coord.centroid,"eucl")

a2.dist=vegdist(sqrt(a2.bio),"bray")
a2.coord.centroid=betadisper(a2.dist,a2.env$Site)$centroids
a2.dist.centroid=vegdist(a2.coord.centroid,"eucl")

dist.centroid=a1.dist.centroid+a2.dist.centroid
coord.centroid=cmdscale(dist.centroid,k=23) # for further distance-based analysis (is it correct ?)


### COMPARING OPTION 1 AND 2
pco.mean=cmdscale(vegdist(sqrt(bio.mean),"bray"))
pco.centroid=cmdscale(dist.centroid)

comparison=procrustes(pco.centroid,pco.mean)
protest(pco.centroid,pco.mean)
```

Comment: Sorry, I could not figure out how to paste my codes correctly. Understand that all what is below the "library(plyr)" is actually R code

Comment: This question appears to be mainly concerned with manipulating matrices in R sand in that case would be off topic here. If there is statistical question behind this please clarify it.

Comment: I would say the first part (perhaps it was in an edit) is statistical, so I am voting to leave it open. Some questions are mixed.

Comment: option 1 and 2 gives differents (close but distincts) results. Is there a theoretical/statistical reason for prefering one over the second?

Comment: Thanks @PeterFlom. Actually I included R codes mainly for beeing sure you get what I mean with my 2 distinct options and for reproducibility purpose.